# Rename a column using a lambda expression

Tags: c#

I have a list of some object

```
List<person>

person.firstname
```

is one property

I would like to change it to

```
person.name
```

How could this be done using a lambda expression?

thanks!

Comment: You can't change property names in code. Explain what you're trying to do and we may be able to help you further.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its not possible to change the property of class but you can create anonymous object using Select method of Linq

```
var persons = person.Select(c=> new {
               name = c.firstname
               //other attributes here 
                });
```